# Chomsky normal form and regular languages

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, context-free, formal-grammars

I'd love your help with the following question:

> Let $G$ be context free grammar in the **Chomksy normal form** with $k$
>   variables.
>
> Is the language $B = \{ w \in L(G) : |w| >2^k \}$ regular ?

What is it about the amount of variables and the Chomsky normal form that is supposed to help me solve this question? I tried to look it up on the web, but besides information about the special form itself, I didn't find an answer to my question.

The answer for the question is that $B$ might be regular.

Comment: Indeed.  The bits about Chomsky normal form and $K$ variables seem to be just distraction.  But maybe there were more parts to the question?

Comment: I guess $B$ is regular if and only if $\mathcal{L}(G)$ is regular.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming that $B$ is regular, then $L(G)=B \cup \lbrace w \in L(G) \mid \vert w \vert \leq 2^k \rbrace$ is also regular because the union of a finite number of regular languages is regular  (especially, $k$ is a constant as the number of variables in the Chomsky normal form).

This can not be true in general because there are context free languages which are not regular.